# 403 Forbidden for rails website on ec2, even when the file permissions are :  lrwxrwxrwx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, capistrano, passenger

I am trying to deploy rails website on ec2 using capistrano, everything works flawlessly but site doesn't show up in the broswer -  403 Forbidden

I am getting this error "symbolic link not allowed or link target not
accessible". More details available on [my blog](http://recipe4developer.wordpress.com/).

**==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==**

```
76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:36:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 483 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:37:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:37:02 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "http://passionate4.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 
(Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:07:43:14 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

---

**==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==**

```
[Thu Nov 17 13:50:56 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 14:48:59 2011] [error] [client 91.132.87.140] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 14:48:59 2011] [error] [client 91.132.87.140] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 18:38:26 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 18:38:27 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 18:38:46 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 18:41:22 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 18:45:15 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
[Thu Nov 17 19:14:31 2011] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Nov 17 19:14:31 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

---

**==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==**

```
www.passionate4.net:80 76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:18:41:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
www.passionate4.net:80 76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:18:45:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
www.passionate4.net:80 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:14:31 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

---

**==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==**

```
[Thu Nov 17 19:40:01 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
```

**==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==**

```
www.passionate4.net:80 76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:40:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 526 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
```

**==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==**

```
[Thu Nov 17 19:40:01 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
```

**==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==**

```
www.passionate4.net:80 76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:19:40:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
```

**==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==**

```
[Thu Nov 17 20:04:37 2011] [error] [client 76.103.107.80] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/apps/capi_app/current
```

**==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==**

```
www.passionate4.net:80 76.103.107.80 - - [17/Nov/2011:20:04:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22"
```

---

**File PERMISSIONS**
`ls -l /var/www/apps/capi_app/current`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 46 2011-11-17 19:04 /var/www/apps/capi_app/current -> /var/www/apps/capi_app/releases/20111117190420
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Resolved this error. I have listed the details on my blog.